# Cefsharp Load Html page issue

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I recently started working with Cefsharp browser in winforms by using the Load method some time its working fine but some times iam not able to render my html file Can some please help me.

```
BrowserSettings settings = new BrowserSettings();
Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());           
CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser webBrowser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser(string.Empty);
webBrowser.Load(@"C:\kiranprac\CEFExample\CEFExample\HTMLResources\html\RTMTables_GetOrder.html");
OrderDetailsPnl.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of many timing issues in Chromium. You sometimes have to wait until the browser finishes the previous step before issuing another command.

In this case, you are constructing the browser with "about:blank", and then changing URL straight afterwards.

The easiest solution here is to supply your URL in the ChromiumWebBrowser constructor instead of calling Load separately.

Answer (score 0):

when you create browser obj, give a valid url.
then load your html text right after. it works at cef v49!.

this works:

```
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://google.com"); //workaround!! yess!!!

var  htmlText = "<html>hello world- this my html</html>"
browser.LoadHtml(htmlText, "http://example/");
```

this doesnt work:

```
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("randomstring"); // silent failll

var  htmlText = "<html>hello world- this my html</html>"
browser.LoadHtml(htmlText, "http://example/");
```

Comment: You should be able to use about:blank instead of making a network request.